# Product page images cache generation issue after Magento upgrade

Tags: product-images, cache, product-page, magento-upgrade, missing

Product page images are showing thumbnails instead of product images. On the same page related products images are showing fine. Only products images are having issues. The image url is accessible but shows thumbnail.

I tried debugging and found that the cache folder for respective product images aren't generating. I have tried giving permissions, changing ownership, deleting cache folder and refreshing page to generate again. But none works.

The catalog:image:resize command generates the cache folders and images are shown after that, but if I flush images cache or creates a product that have different image name which will require new cache folder, then issue appears again.

Is their any permanent solution rather than just running catalog:image:resize command again n again?

I have upgraded my Magento from 2.1.7 to 2.3.4

Comment: Yes, similar issue exists at my end please update when get resolved.